# How to calculate sine/cosine of a real number? And how to compare them?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Okay so I have come across an exercise that wants me to compare some outputs of functions. However, I have to do this without a calculator [Here it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNz5u.png)

How can I calculate sine/cosine of a real number without using calculator? I noticed a "Taylor expansion" method but we haven't learned that yet, I tried to take the number for sine, divide it by 180 and multiply it by π, but what about cosine? 
I will by very thankful for every response.

Comment: You need https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities exactly values are not required

Comment: Incidentally, the fourth claim on the list is false.

Comment: Note: $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1$ always and $\cos x = \cos(-x)$ always and that  $0 < 1 < \frac \pi 2< 3 < \pi$ and that $\frac \pi 2 - 1\approx \frac {3.14}2-1 = 0.57$ and $\pi - 3 \approx 3.14 - 3 = 0.14$.  That should be enough to get you to answer verify (refute) all the questions.

Comment: This excercise has *nothing* to do with calculating but using your $\sin(-x) =-\sin(x); \cos(-x)=\cos(x); \sin(\pi \pm x)=\mp\sin(x); \cos(\pi\pm x)=-\cos x$ and depending on the quadrant $\cos x = \sin (\frac \pi 2 \pm x)$ identities.  We are only comparing values as they appear on the quadrant.  Use $0 < 1 < \frac \pi 2 < 2 < 3 < \pi$ and $0<\pi - 3 < 1$.

Answer (score 1):

To show that $a>b$, you often need to calculate neither $a$, nor $b$.

There are different techniques to do it. I will demonstrate 2 most common of them with your first example of $\sin 1>\sin3$.

#### 1. Show that $a-b>0$:

$$\sin1-\sin3 = 2\cos\frac{1+3}2\sin\frac{1-3}2=2\cos(2)\sin(-1)$$
Let's analyze the signs of factors:

Since $3<\pi<3.2$, $\pi/2<1.6<2<3<\pi$. That means angle of 2 radians lies in the second quadrant and its cosine is negative: $\cos2<0$.

Since $\sin(-1)=-\sin 1$ and $0<1<\pi/2$, we conclude that $\sin(-1)<0$ as well. Thus, $2\cos(2)\sin(-1)$ is positive.

#### 2. Show that $a>c$ and $d>b$, where $c\ge d$ and usually can be calculated.

Let's consider $c=\sin\frac\pi4=\frac1{\sqrt2}$ and $d=\sin\frac{3\pi}4=\frac1{\sqrt2}$. On the interval $[0,\frac\pi2]$ function $\sin x$ is strictly increasing, so if $1>\frac\pi4$, then $\sin1>\sin\frac\pi4$.

Likewise, on the interval $[\frac\pi2,\pi]$ function $\sin x$ is strictly decreasing, so from $3>\frac{3\pi}4$ follows $\sin 3 < \sin\frac{3\pi}4$

Finally:
$$
\sin1 > \sin\frac\pi4 = \sin\frac{3\pi}4 > \sin 3
$$

Answer (score 0):

You can't in general but there are trig identities to do specific values.  (for example if you need to figure out $\sin 15^\circ=x$ we can figure that out noting $\frac 12 = \sin 30^\circ = \sin 2*15^\circ = 2\sin 15^\circ\cos 15^\circ = 2x(\sqrt{1 - x^2})$ and solving for $x$).

But you don't need to do **ANY** of that here.

Also I should point out these are assuming radians and *NOT* angles.  So no need to divide by $180$ and multiply by $\pi$.

1) $\sin 1 > \sin 3$.  This is just a matter of noting $0 < 1 < \frac \pi 2 < 3 < \pi$

So $\sin 1$ is in the first quadrant and is positive. And $\sin 3$ is in the second quadrant and is positive.  But $\sin 3 = \sin (\pi - 0.1415...) =\sin (0.1415....)$.  And $\sin (0.1415....)$ is in first quandrant.  As $0 < 0.1415...< 1 < \frac \pi 2$ then $\sin 3 = \sin (0.1415....) < \sin 1$.

And the rest are done by similar *logic*.  ***No*** calculations.

2) $\sin (3-\pi) = \sin (-0.1415....)$ and $-\frac \pi 2 < -0.1415... < 0$ so this is in the fourth quadrant and negative.....

Can you do the rest?

....

Except $\sin^2 1 + \cos^2 1 = 2$ is obviously *wrong*.  $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x= 1$ *always*.